# Why are some maven projects in IntelliJ grayed out?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Why are some maven projects in IntelliJ greyed out?

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue. So I deleted the project, the .idea folder, then reloaded from scratch and that issue disappeared.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Seems images are better way to answer this question.

1. Projects are greyed out when you ignore them in your IntelliJ workspace.

[image: Ignored Projects]

2. To add those projects or modules back in your workspace, right click on them and click on **unignore projects** as shown in below screenshot.

[image: Ignored Projects back in Workspace]

3. Alternatively, you can also go to File - Settings -> Build, execution and deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Ignored Files, now select whichever projects/modules you may wish to retain in your IntelliJ workspace.

[image]

Comment: Do you know why this happens sporadically, that Intellij ignores modules?

Comment: should not happen. In fact app is more stable now.

Comment: Spent a whole day not knowing what's happening with my workspace. This finally resolved it. But, I am not sure why it would ignore my mvn modules without me doing any action. I am using 2019.3 community edition.

Comment: Thank you @PratikAmbani, this does happen sporadically though, not sure why, it has happened three times already, the first time I had to create a new project, but this time I was deep in the project and everytime I create that specific module it shows ignored pom

Comment: @JamesOkpeGeorge Glad it worked! Upvote would surely help if answer is correct :P

Answer (score 10):

Right click on the pom -> maven -> unignore.  Then right click on pom -> maven -> reload project.

Seems some kind of bug when you open a child subdirectory then open the parent in IntelliJ.

Comment: I can confirm that this behaviour (ignored maven projects when adding parent maven projects) still occurs for intellij 2022.2.3.

Comment: You could report it to them and leave us a link to vote for the issue? :)

Comment: I saw this behaviour yesterday but can not reproduce it now, sorry. As others said it seems to occur sporadically only ...

Answer (score 1):

This is known issue and interlinked to 3 more IDEA issue. You can find more details here.

[Indicate that pom.xml is ignored when editing it](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-164626)

Lot of us might spend more time and then end up deleting module & re-creating it.
But @Pratik Ambani solutions works great!!, option 3 worked in my case.